# prismic graphql querying single user

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm trying to figure out how to query a single user from graphql schema by id. I'm using the graphiql tool and I'm able to get all Users.

```
{
    allPrismicUsers {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        data {
          name
        }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Outputs :**

```
{
  "data": {
    "allPrismicUsers”: {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Prismic__User__WzKFwywAABmiZk_4",
            "data": {
              "name": “John Doe”
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Prismic__User__WzKDZywAABmiZkYp",
            "data": {
              "name": “Jane Doe“
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Prismic__User__WzKGDiwAAJSiZlFL",
            "data": {
              "name": “Cat Doe”
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I also have prismicUser() on the schema

```
query {
  prismicUser {
    id
    data {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "prismicUser": {
      "id": "Prismic__User__WzKGDiwAAJSiZlFL",
      "data": {
        "name": "Cat Doe"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to query a user based on a specific id but not sure if I'm querying the wrong way. 
I tried this.

```
query {
  prismicLocation(id: "Prismic__User__WzKDZywAABmiZkYp") {
    data {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error

> {   "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Argument \"id\" has invalid value \"Prismic__User__WzKDZywAABmiZkYp\".\nExpected
>   \"prismicUserIdQueryString_2\", found not an object.",
>         "users": [
>           {
>             "line": 25,
>             "column": 23
>           }
>         ]
>       }   ] }

**How can I call a specific user based on their id ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Gatsby GraphQL reference](https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#graphql-reference), Gatsby allows you to filter results by any field in GraphQL (using operators such as `eq`, `ne`, etc.)

The `gatsby-source-prismic` plugin provides a field called `prismicId` (i.e. `W1syKSIAAAzdN1Jg`).

Here is an example query:

```
{
  prismicUser(prismicId:{eq:"WzKDZywAABmiZkYp"}) {
    data {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But you can also query by `id`:

```
prismicUser(id:{eq:"Prismic__User__WzKDZywAABmiZkYp"})
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe this really helps, very much appreciated. I'm getting 503 errors on Gatsby GraphQL reference page ? Anywhere else I can ready or have examples of how to traverse through queries. Be great to have a reference list showing code examples somewhere. My guess is thats what the Gatsby GraphQL reference is trying to do if the 503 wasn't there.

Comment: Gabe is there any reason why I wouldn't use the filter option on the allPrismicUsers using prismicId ? Or is it faster to use prismicUser instead. Not sure what the difference is between the two apart from one returns all and the other only returns 1 ? So I presume prismicUser is the way to go in this case ??